# How to create CSS Buttons that appear on hover within a flex container?

Tags: css, flexbox, navbar

I'm trying to put some buttons onto some flex containers for a sort of middle-of-the-page dropdown menu. I need four buttons that fill the space of the flex container, that appear on hover. I can get the hover action working, but my buttons don't show up and are a little off. I'm very new at this and have really hit a wall here.

Essentially, I need a box that splits into 4 other clickable boxes on hover, all contained inside the original box.

```css
.nav-box-container {
  width: 220px;
  margin: 15px 7px 0px 7px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-box-container {
    width: auto;
  }


  .nav-box-citations {
    color: #282828;
    background-color: #fff;
    outline: 3px solid #bbb;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 25px 25px 30px 25px;
    padding-right: 19px;
    min-height: 160px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .nav-box-citations-buttons {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    outline: #282828 solid;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .nav-box-citations:hover,
  .nav-box-citations:focus+.nav-box-citations-buttons,
  .nav-box-citations-buttons:hover {
    display: inline;
  }
```

```html
     <div class="nav-box-container">
       <div class="nav-box-citations">
         <h3 class="nav-box-title">Citation Guides</h3>
         <p class="nav-box-desc">Get help on formatting citations and bibliographies.</p>
         <div class="btn-grp">
           <button type="button-group" class=nav-box-citations-buttons><a href="#">APA</a></button>
           <button type="button-group" class=nav-box-citations-buttons><a href="#">MLA</a></button>
           <button type="button-group" class=nav-box-citations-buttons><a href="#">AMA</a></button>
           <button type="button-group" class=nav-box-citations-buttons><a href="#">Chicago</a></button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Produces this:

[image: on view]

[image: on hover]

Comment: Hi! welcome to SO. you wrote your question pretty good :) BUT FYI, you should embed images inside your post instead of using links (most people won't click on links from strangers), so I edited your question a bit. if you can, it would be helpful to describe your goal a bit more. I'm not sure what is your end goal, where do you except the divs to be, what should be in them, explain what did you try to do.

Comment: What I'm trying tot do is have four equal-sized buttons the size of the citation guide box that show up on hover. so when the user looks at the site, and mouses over the box in the screenshot, four options show up all contained within the original box

Comment: You *think* `.nav-box-container` is a flexbox cointainer, but it is not defined as such with `display: flex`. Also, `flex-grow` has only effect on child elements of a flexbox container. And your CSS is missing a closing curly brace (`}`) from defining the @media query making the buttons show on any device wider than `max-width: 767px`. This may be what you want, but that would be accidental.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to target just the **children of** the ***hovered* parent**:

```css
  .nav-box-citations:hover .nav-box-citations-buttons {
    display: inline;
  }
```

```css
  .nav-box-container {
  width: 220px;
  margin: 15px 7px 0px 7px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-box-container {
    width: auto;
  }
  .nav-box-citations {
    color: #282828;
    background-color: #fff;
    outline: 3px solid #bbb;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 25px 25px 30px 25px;
    padding-right: 19px;
    min-height: 160px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .nav-box-citations-buttons {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    outline: #282828 solid;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .nav-box-citations:hover .nav-box-citations-buttons {
    display: inline;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav-box-container">
  <div class="nav-box-citations">
    <h3 class="nav-box-title">Citation Guides</h3>
    <p class="nav-box-desc">Get help on formatting citations and bibliographies.</p>
    <div class="btn-grp">
      <button type="button-group" class=nav-box-citations-buttons>
      <a href="#">APA</a>
      </button>
      <button type="button-group" class=nav-box-citations-buttons>
      <a href="#">MLA</a>
      </button>
      <button type="button-group" class=nav-box-citations-buttons>
      <a href="#">AMA</a>
      </button>
      <button type="button-group" class=nav-box-citations-buttons>
      <a href="#">Chicago</a>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should've known, thank you. The hover works now, but I'm still unsure which element to use to make my button column fill the entire container on hover. This box is one of 5 on the homepage, and I'd like it not to stretch the rest of the containers when hovered

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not to stretch the rest of the containers", they do not go beyond their own parent container in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/og0x2pwd/

Comment: I'm not sure what's going in your fiddle there, but the hover isn't working at all.  When it hovers in my system it simply adds the button group at the bottom of the nav box, when it would like it to start at the top of the navbox and fill the whole container

Comment: Oh, I see now it's the `.btn-grp` needs absolute, flex, etc. https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/og0x2pwd/1/ look at css: lines 27-46